# C - time_t string representation

Tags: c, time-t

I am new to C programming and I would like some help with a simple task.

So I have this function:

```
char *time2str(time_t time) {
     static_char *str_fmt = "%02d/%02d/%4d %02d:%02d";
     char *time_s = "";

     return time_s;
}
```

What I would like to do is get in DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM format the time and store it in time_s variable so that I can return it. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to format the string and store it WITHOUT printing it. All I have found so far is the sprint method that actually prints the formatted string when storing it too, which is not what I want.

In a few words, I would just like the time from time_t time in the format I mentioned stored in time_s.

Sorry if I didn't explain everything properly but I'm new in C programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `sprintf` which is similar to `printf` but "prints" the result into a buffer rather than on the screen.

Returning the pointer to a static buffer:

```
char *time2str(time_t time) {
     static_char *str_fmt = "%02d/%02d/%4d %02d:%02d";

     static char time_s[20];                             // ugly, 20 is hopefully enough
  // ^ static is important here, because we return a pointer to time_s
  //   and without static, the time_s buffer will no longer exist once the
  //   time2str function is finished

     sprintf(time_s, str_fmt, time.....);
     return time_s;
}
```

or (better), we provide a buffer (long enough) where the converted string is to be placed:

```
void time2str(time_t time, char *time_s) {
     static_char *str_fmt = "%02d/%02d/%4d %02d:%02d";
     sprintf(time_s, str_fmt, time.....);
     return time_s;
}
...
char mytime[20];                                         // ugly, 20 is hopefully enough
time2str(time, mytime);
printf("mytime: %s\n, mytime);
```

or the time2str function returns a newly allocated buffer that will contain the converted string. That buffer must be freed later with `free`.

```
char *time2str(time_t time) {
     static_char *str_fmt = "%02d/%02d/%4d %02d:%02d";
     char *time_s = malloc(20);                          // ugly, 20 is hopefully enough
     sprintf(time_s, str_fmt, time.....);
     return time_s;
}
...
char *mytime = time2str(time);
printf("mytime: %s\n, mytime);
free(mytime);
```

Completing the arguments of `sprintf` is left as an exercise to the reader.

Disclaimer: non tested, non error checking code meant only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Generally speaking, always use at least `snprintf`. It is *so* easy to create buffer overflow with plain `sprintf`!

Answer (score 1):

The function `ctime` takes a `time_t` and outputs a string in a fixed format. If that is not sufficient for your task you should use `strftime`. This has a whole bunch of format specifiers that should suit your need.

It works on `struct tm`, so you'd first have to convert your `time_t` to that using `localtime` or `gmtime`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strftime()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.3.5), after converting your `time_t` value to `struct tm` type.

Answer (score 0):

in general,

1. call `time()` to get the current time into a `time_t` variable
2. call `localtime()` to get a pointer to a `struct tm` structure with the time information in separate fields
3. call `strftime()` to get the desired time/date format.

Suggest reading the man pages for `localtime()` and for `strftime()` to get all the details

here is a sample code, where you would need to modify the strftime() format string for what you want to have in the resulting char array.

```
time_t     currentTimeSec = time(NULL);
struct tm *tmStructptr;
char       timeStamp[128];

tmStructptr = localtime( &currentTimeSec );
strftime( timeStamp, sizeof(timeStamp), "YOUR FORMAT STRING" tmStructptr );
```

Note: to only extract the day of the week, the format string would be: "%w"